Grand guignol horror movie from the late 60s/early 70s
Okay, this question is for the hardcore horror film buffs...
It is a horror movie I saw as a child, made in the late 60s or early 70s, and the only thing I remember was the final scene:  The hero enters a room and there is a shelf or row of shelves containing a bunch of severed heads, all laid out like trophies.  The villain enters the room wielding (I believe) a sword and says to the hero, "I WANT YOUR HEAD!"  There is a fight and the villain is defeated.
I'm thinking it had to be one of those intriguingly lurid entries from Hammer Studios.  Anyone who can point me to the right title will resolve a 40 year-old mystery!

So, it was a color, English-speaking film? You mention Hammer, which is nearly entirely English in casting. Did the actors have accents?

Hi Vicpylon.  I really don't remember about the accents.  It's certainly possible.  The reason I mention Hammer is because those films seemed to have a particular emphasis on decapitations.

I am not sure but could it be The Flesh and Blood Show from 1972?
There is a scene in a basement with a shelf full of wax heads, only that one of the heads is not wax at all but belongs to one of the actresses in the group.

Your welcome! The whole movie is available on YouTube, the scene begins at approximately 19:00

I saw the movie.  It wasn't the one I was looking for, but it was in that same overall genre -- a lurid (but fun) low-budget Pete Walker/Samuel Z. Arkoff/Roger Corman/AIP/Hammer-style horror film.
